# mapeo de un JSON en una clase java

Tags: java, json, class, serialización, jackson

Tengo el siguiente JSON:

```
[{"estado":true,"cod":0,"id":"1237273960","dispositivo":"123456789012345","ELEMENTO":"AU","nom_ATRIBUTO":"ARBPL","val_ATRIBUTO":"DCF9D2_1","fecha":1585519200000,"descargado":"N"},{"estado":true,"cod":1,"id":"1237273961","dispositivo":"123456789012345","tip_ELEMENTO":"OT","nom_ATRIBUTO":"ARBPL","val_ATRIBUTO":"DCF9D2_1","fecha":1585519200000,"descargado":"N"}]
```

Y la clase GOT que equivale a los objetos que componen el JSON

```
public class GOT {

private Integer cod;
private String id;
private String dispositivo;
private String ELEMENTO;
private String nom_ATRIBUTO;
private String val_ATRIBUTO;
private Date fecha;
private String descargado;  
private boolean estado = true;


public boolean isEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(boolean estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

public Integer getCOD() {       
    return cod;
}

public void setCOD(Integer cOD) {
    cod = cOD;
}

public String getID() {
    return id;
}

public void setID(String iD) {
    id = iD;
}

public String getDISPOSITIVO() {
    return dispositivo;
}

public void setDISPOSITIVO(String dISPOSITIVO) {
    dispositivo = dISPOSITIVO;
}

public String getELEMENTO() {
    return ELEMENTO;
}

public void setELEMENTO(String eLEMENTO) {
    ELEMENTO = eLEMENTO;
}

public String getNOM_ATRIBUTO() {
    return nom_ATRIBUTO;
}

public void setNOM_ATRIBUTO(String nOM_ATRIBUTO) {
    nom_ATRIBUTO = nOM_ATRIBUTO;
}

public String getVAL_ATRIBUTO() {   
    return val_ATRIBUTO;
}

public void setVAL_ATRIBUTO(String vAL_ATRIBUTO) {
    val_ATRIBUTO = vAL_ATRIBUTO;
}

public String getDESCARGADO() { 
    return descargado;
}

public void setDESCARGADO(String dESCARGADO) {
    descargado = dESCARGADO;
}

public Date getFECHA() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFECHA(Date fECHA) {
    fecha = fECHA;
}
}
```

Para trabajar con ese JSON, he creado la clase impor que equivale al JSON, o eso entiendo ya que no tengo mucha experiencia con esta tecnología.

```
public class Impor {

GOT[] datos;

public GOT[] getDatos() {
    return datos;
}

public void setDatos(GOT[] datos) {
    this.datos = datos;
}
```

}

Para el mapeo del JSON uso Jackson.

```
InputStream datos = request.getInputStream();
Impor datosAlmacenar = new ObjectMapper().readValue(datos, Impor.class);
```

Pero obtengo la siguiente traza de error y no entiendo el motivo.

```
Cannot deserialize instance of `com.paquete.ajax.model.Impor` out of START_ARRAY token at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

El error está en la clase Impor pero no veo donde ya que, hasta donde yo llego, esa clase equivale al JSON.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, ya que llevo todo el día de hoy dándole vueltas a este problema y no veo la solución

Comment: Creo que para poder hacer el mapper como lo esta intentando hacer, el JSON debe tener una estructura similar a `{datos : [ {"estado":true,"cod":0,...}, {.....} ] }`.

Comment: Voy a probarlo! Gracias!

Comment: @isaac muchas gracias por la ayuda!!  Me has solucionado el problema.

Comment: Que bien, que te haya solucionado el problema, puese el comentario en las respuestas para que por favor la marques como que te soluciono tu inconveniente. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que para poder hacer el mapper como lo esta intentando hacer, el JSON debe tener una estructura similar a

```
{datos : [ {"estado":true,"cod":0,...}, {.....} ] }
```

Donde `datos` corresponde al nombre de la variable `GOT[] datos;` de la clase `Import`